# How to set a view at specific position on screen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

How to can I set a view at a specific point on the screen programmatically? I want use a Point like `x` and `y`. I **don't** want it to `translateX` or `translateY`. I want for example to set a view to the Point `x: 0` and `y: 0` that means it needs to be at the top left of the screen. How can I achieve that?

I was trying this but the view translates X and Y what I don't want.

```kotlin
val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

val inflatedView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_change_font_size_right, null, false)

inflatedView.popup_xml_view.x = 0f
inflatedView.popup_xml_view.y = 0f
```

Comment: You could try to place target view to root view of the window. And the root view must have match_parent for both dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Android had a [layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout) that would support this requirements, but I think that it was pretty bad in regards to performance and it was deprecated (I hope that I am not wrong making this affirmation). However, the same behaviour can be implemented using a `FrameLayout` and add the views in that layout.

To add a view at a particular position, you create its layout params to set a width and a height, then set the margins which will position your view as absolute coordinates (the dimension is in pixels):

```
val imageView = ImageView(this)
imageView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_red_dark)
imageView.layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height).apply {
    setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
}
root.addView(imageView)
```

For a height/width of 200 and margins of (100, 100, 0, 0), it will look something like the image below (run on an emulated Pixel 3).

[image: screenshot]

NOTE: [Here](https://youtu.be/IrMw7MEgADk?t=1212) is a talk where they talk about this approach to emulate the `AbsoulteLayout` and why they "killed" it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margins = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
margins.topMargin = 100;
margins.leftMargin = 200;
```

Alternatively use animate:

```
view.animate().x(x).y(y).setDuration(0).start();
```